# Hibernate / Spring JPA, combining @Version and @DynamicUpdate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a question for JPA / Hibernate experts.
In my application all my entities inherit from a "Base intenty" that hold Id, cretedDate, Version and all fields common to all the the entities of the application.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The constant serialVersionUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * The Id.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * The Created date.
     */
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", name = "createddate")
    @CreatedDate
    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonIgnore
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    /**
     * The Updated date.
     */
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", name = "updateddate")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    private ZonedDateTime updatedDate;

    /**
     * The Version.
     */
    @Version
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT DEFAULT 1")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer version;

    /**
     * The constant logger.
     */
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BaseEntity.class.getName());

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Base entity.
     */
    public BaseEntity() {
    }
    [....]
}
```

But it happens that one of the entities ( one of the 120 tables of the database) is generating un-necessary Optimistic lock exception because it is a table that should not have required the @version, so I was thinking of adding :

```
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
@DynamicUpdate
```

for this particular entity.

I cannot remove the inheritance of BaseIntity for this class because, the abstract JPA repository is expecting a class extending BaseEntity

```
@NoRepositoryBean interface CustomRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable>
    extends Repository<T, ID>, Serializable {
```

So my question is the following :

What will be the behaviour of Hibernate / JPA, if an entity both has a     @Version column defined through its parent but has the @DynamicUpdate also activated locally.

What will happen ? I checked it compiles and runs fine, but before putting this version in production i was wondering if it could have side effects...

Answer (score 1):

You can use that approach, but I would recommend you try to get away from such a limiting model and move the versioning parts into a subclass `VersionedBaseEntity`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, this is what I did, but this required creating a separate package for the VersionedRepository as JPA does not support having 2 repositories in same package, it was not so complicated in the end with the help of a good IDE and plugins...